# Upload image to FTP in Android using lib SimpleFTP

Tags: java, android, ftp

I want to upload file to FTP. I'm using simpleftp.jar. This is my code, it always failed stopped working

MainActivity.java

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.jibble.simpleftp.SimpleFTP;

import java.io.File;

import java.io.IOException;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static int RESULT_LOAD_IMG = 1;
    String imgDecodableString;

    Button btn;

    TextView tv;
    static final String FTP_HOST= "ftp://ftp.lomapod.esy.es/";

    /*********  FTP USERNAME ***********/
    static final String FTP_USER = "xxxxxxxxxx";

    /*********  FTP PASSWORD ***********/
    static final String FTP_PASS  ="xxxxxxxxx";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        btn=(Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonUploadPicture);
        tv=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                File f = new File(imgDecodableString);
                String name=f.getName();

                // Upload sdcard file
                uploadFile(name);
            }
        });
    }

//    public void onClick(View v){
//
////        Bundle b=new Bundle();
////        Intent i=new Intent(getApplication(), DetailTransActivity.class);
////        Toast.makeText(this, "Upload Bukti Transaksi Berhasil",
////                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
////        i.putExtras(b);
////        startActivity(i);
//
//    }

    public void loadImagefromGallery(View view) {
        // Create intent to Open Image applications like Gallery, Google Photos
        Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        // Start the Intent
        startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, RESULT_LOAD_IMG);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        try {
            // When an Image is picked
            if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMG && resultCode == RESULT_OK
                    && null != data) {
                // Get the Image from data


                Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
                String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

                // Get the cursor
                Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                        filePathColumn, null, null, null);
                // Move to first row
                cursor.moveToFirst();

                int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
                String filename = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                imgDecodableString = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                cursor.close();

                File f= new File(""+imgDecodableString);
                f.getName();
                ImageView imgView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgView);
                // Set the Image in ImageView after decoding the String
                imgView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory
                        .decodeFile(imgDecodableString));

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Pilih Bukti Transaksi",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Upload Bukti Transaksi Gagal", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
        }
    }

    public void uploadFile(String fileName){


        try {
            SimpleFTP ftp = new SimpleFTP();

            // Connect to an FTP server on port 21.
            ftp.connect(FTP_HOST, 21, FTP_USER, FTP_PASS);

            // Set binary mode.
            ftp.bin();

            // Change to a new working directory on the FTP server.
            ftp.cwd("/assets/");

            // Upload some files.
            ftp.stor(new File(fileName));


            // Quit from the FTP server.
            ftp.disconnect();
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Success",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            // Jibble.
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Failed",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

It always give me this error. When i click the error it directed to

ftp.connect(FTP_HOST, 21, FTP_USER, FTP_PASS);

```
05-08 22:17:43.126 24537-24537/com.amobi.imageuploading E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                          android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
                                                                              at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1117)
                                                                              at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:385)
                                                                              at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
                                                                              at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)
                                                                              at java.net.Socket.tryAllAddresses(Socket.java:108)
                                                                              at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:177)
                                                                              at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:149)
                                                                              at org.jibble.simpleftp.SimpleFTP.connect(SimpleFTP.java:68)
                                                                              at com.amobi.imageuploading.MainActivity.uploadFile(MainActivity.java:121)
                                                                              at com.amobi.imageuploading.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:49)
                                                                              at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)
                                                                              at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)
                                                                              at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
                                                                              at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Can anyone help me to find the cause of this error? Thank you

Comment: You can put upload file code in a thread or use asynctask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just put this block of code after `setContentView();`

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
}
```

Comment: What is that for?? It's solve the stop responding. But the result is failed. 
Can you help me? why is that happening?

Comment: where should i put it? i already put it after setContentView. Should i put it in another place too? –

Comment: do you have the same  Exception?

Comment: i already understand what do you mean . .
Haha thanks a lot for your help

Comment: StrictMode is the wrong way to do it. It will solve your problem but the right way to do it is with an AsyncTask. Please consult this thread on more information on how to proceed. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22292953/how-to-run-this-code-in-a-thread-or-async-task

Answer (score 0):

You can read about NetworkOnMainThreadException [here](http://simpledeveloper.com/network-on-main-thread-error-solution/). NetworkOnMainThreadException is a very popular exception if you are using networking operations.